# Android - Cannot resolve symbol 'KmlLayer'

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I am working on an app that uses Google Maps.
I want to load a polygon from a KML file.
To my understanding I should be using the KmlLayer class and a bunch of others, but I can't seem to find the dependency I have to add in order for it to happen. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The dependency to add in your Build.gradle is today (Dec. 2020):

```
  implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.0.3'
```

and the import is now including a `.data`as stated by `meh` below:

```
import com.google.maps.android.data.kml.KmlLayer;
```

Answer (score 1):

this class is a part of this library 
[android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils)

There is a demo project in github , that can help you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, the package name for the KmlLayer was changed to:

```
import com.google.maps.android.data.kml.KmlLayer;
```

And it used to be `com.google.maps.android.kml.KmlLayer`